# Inserting >75k records into MongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I have a sails.js application with MongoDB. I use Waterline ORM to interact with my database. I have an array called `phoneNumbers` of some 75k phone numbers where each item in the array is an object like:

```
{
    name: 'Foo',
    phoneNumbers: 123,
    groupName: 'Bar'        // The name of the group (unique field in database)
}
```

Now, I also have a collection in the database called `groups` and when inserting the phone numbers into the `phoneNumbers` collection, I need to fetch the group ID from the groups collection (for each item in the array using the `groupName` key that you see in the object above) and add another key to object like this:

```
{
    name: 'Foo',
    phoneNumber: 123,
    groupName: 'Bar'        // The name of the group (unique field in database)
    groupId: '123baz'   // The group ID from the groups collection in MongoDB
}
```

This way, I can run queries where I can fetch all the phone numbers that belong to a certain group ID instead of using the group name.

I am trying to accomplish this by using the `async` NPM package.

```
var async = require('async');

var phoneNumbersWithGroupId = [];
async.each(phoneNumbers, function(phoneNumber, callback) {
    Groups.find({ name: phoneNumber.groupName }).exec(function(err, group) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            var number = phoneNumber;
            number['groupId'] = group[0].id;

            phoneNumbersWithGroupId.push(number);
            callback();
        }
    });
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
            success     : false,
            statusCode  : 500,
            data        : 'Server error'
        });
    }
});

// Insert the phone numbers into the database
PhoneNumbers.create(phoneNumbersWithGroupId).exec(function(err, newRecords) {
    res.send('Inserted');
});
```

I can't seem to get this to work for some reason. I get two errors.

### Error 1

This error gets thrown on the terminal for the number of items I have in the array (around 75,000).

```
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
    at Server.destroy (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:670:47)
    at Server.close (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:367:17)
    at Db.close (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:333:19)
    at /Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:138:14
    at /Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:187:20
    at /Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:239:13
    at _arrayEach (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:91:13)
    at _each (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:82:13)
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:238:9)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:215:22)
    at Object.module.exports.adapter.teardown (/Users/Nagarjun/Code/slashquote/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:137:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/index.js:244:19
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:122:13
    at _each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
    at Object.async.each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:121:9)
    at Sails.hook.teardown (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/index.js:241:13)

Details:  MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed
```

### Error 2

The I get this error in the end: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`.

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to accomplish these insertions?

Comment: For **error 2**, you're running into the fact that you're running the create statement before the array is populated, so it always sends 'Inserted' back as the response, before **error 1** occurs. For **error 1**, you're probably overwhelming the database by sending 75k requests to it *very* rapidly. You should break these into chunks and request them a chunk at a time rather than 1 at a time, possibly even in series rather than parallel.

Comment: How would I break them into chunks? If you are suggesting using https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#series-tasks-callback, I don't seem to understand how to loop through the array of objects to accomplish this.

Comment: Basically, you take your giant 75k length array and turn it into a collection of smaller arrays, or, chunks.

Comment: Look into MongoDB references: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Comment: @Steve That is kinda what I am doing but I don't want to reference based on name. I instead want to fetch the id from the groups collection and reference it that way. Hence, the database queries. Any suggestion on how I can do this without overwhelming the database?

Comment: 2 suggestions: 
1. use eachLimit instead of each to limit the concurrent open connections to mongo
2. move PhoneNumbers.create to async.eachLimit callback, in your code it is being called without connection to the each loop termination (probably called while it's still running)